# Custom field suite not showing in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/ to create a loop field. It is working fine for other post but not working for a custom post types `works`

I have registered this custom post type as:

```
 register_post_type('works', array(
            'labels'              => array(
                'name'                => _x( 'Works', 'Post Type General Name', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'singular_name'       => _x( 'Work', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'Works', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Work', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'all_items'           => __( 'All Works', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'view_item'           => __( 'View Work', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Work', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Work', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'update_item'         => __( 'Update Work', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Search Work', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'famous_kitchens' ),
                'new_item'           => __( 'New Work' ),
            ),


            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
            // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
//            'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' )
            'hierarchical'        => true,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 20,
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => false,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'post',
            'show_in_rest'        => true,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-food',
            'query_var'           => true,
            'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'works' ),

        ));
```

[image]

Above is the screen shot, I have selected works on post type but it is not showing this field in admin section. When I say admin section, I can't add the gallery because I can't find this gallery field in single work post type.

But, if I select single post from post equals to then, it will be shown on the post type. It is not working when I selected post types as works

Comment: your post type slug is "Work" only so please change works to Work and try

Comment: could you please explain little bit why you think so? Here, I have written: `'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'works' ),`

Comment: @FullStop Also, I haven't written that some random text, I had typed `wor` and there it shows all the post types and I had picked one type from there.

Comment: please once create post type via plugin and check. plugin is "Custom post type"